# How to avoid communication to be sent during a data migration?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-migration

in Marketing Cloud integrated with Sales Cloud, we have many journey builders (triggered on creation/edit of salesforce data event) and some triggered sends. Sales Cloud has to do a data migration during the dont want to send any email/sms...
For this we plan to stop all the JBs and deactivate the TSs during the migration and the restart them when the migration is finished.
Please is this the only solution to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: It's a little bit "Hacky" but one thing you could do might be to deliberately remove SFMC access tokens so that CRM has no way of firing JB Events or Triggered Sends and then re-establish them after you've completed migration - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_clear_invalid_tokens.htm&type=5

Comment: if you can hold out a couple more weeks, you should be able to pause Journeys through UI and API "soon" (end of june 2020, so say the release notes...) : 1) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_pause.htm  2) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_may_2020_dev_journey_pause.htm&type=5 - 
this should be much easier than stopping them, which I agree, could be a pain. Pausing TS sounds like an ok thing to do via UI or API.

Comment: @JonasLamberty, yes I saw the next release but this is to be done before the end of this month

Comment: thank you, guys. So you confirm that at the moment stopping/restarting is the way to go?

Comment: You say it's a lot of journeys, so maybe this is not feasible - but you could change Journeys to a version which contains only one Update Contact Event, simply catching all users in a data extension instead of normal processing.
When you start over, make a new version based on the last "real" one and inject everyone in the data extension once more, if still necessary. Could be a lot of effort, maybe only do it for the top 5 journeys etc.

Comment: thanks @JonasLamberty but they are more than 20